# Worksheet Calculate does not run from personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

My Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() runs when I place it into Sheet1(Sheet1) as a part of VBAProject (Book1) but it doesn't when I place it into Sheet1(Sheet1) as a part of VBAProject (PERSONAL.XLSB).

Why is that the case? What shall I do to make it run?

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(LastRow, 2).Offset(1, 0) = Cells(2, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AndrewFan I have edited my post and added my code. I would like to be able to save this code somewhere, so that I can use it whenever required. That is why I thought of saving it under personal.xlsb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PERSONAL.XLSB is a hidden workbook that doesn't usually have formulas or anything else on its sheets.  No formulas so nothing to calculate and the event never fires.

Comment: I have edited my post and added some code. Where can I save my code to run it for any excel file, even for a brand new workbook that I have opened and not saved yet? Thanks!